# Share screen between PC and tablet without internet connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, remote-desktop, lan, remote-control

I have a computer that is on it's own network without internet connection (for security reasons), is there any way to screen mirroring this pc on a tablet (android, ipad or windows) so i can move around in the store and have it with me ??

I though about adding a wireless adapter to the pc and create a wireless hotspot, connect the tablet to this wifi, but i'm not sure that this will give me an enough range to move free.

Comment: Are the tablet and the PC on the same network (physically) and it's just a setting that prevents the PC from using the internet or is there no connection available so far?

Comment: There is no connection available between them now. How can the tablet be on the same network as the PC when this network is just lan without wifi? is that possible ?

Comment: No but it's why I asked for clarification. On it's own network could've just as well meant on a different subnet and as you're saying network it would imply there is more than that one PC, possibly a router which could have WiFi. If you don't have any means to connect a WiFi device to that network you will have to create on in order to let them talk to each other. You could use that wireless adapter, an access point or a WiFi capable router as an example. Does that computer run Windows? There are remote desktop solutions available for mobile devices. Probably for Linux as well.

Comment: unfortunately there is no router, it is just a switch. Yes it is running windows 7. Ok so you suggest too to connect a wireless adapter to this pc and create a hotspot poin ?

Comment: That would depend on your circumstances. While you defined your goal you didn't really give any circumstances. You mentioned a store you want to move around in. So how much distance is there between the store floor and the PC? How many and what kind of walls? Depending on it, it could be a better idea to use a wireless AP or exchange the switch for a router with WiFi capabilities.